# How to disable hal browser in Spring Boot data rest

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I Don't have HAL browser or explorer in my dependencies. But it was already enable in root of my project: `http:127.0.0.1:8080/` or `http:127.0.0.1:8080/profile`

How can I remove or disable HAL?

Here is my dependencies in `pom.xml` :

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and now HAL browser was removed from my project.

At all when you use `spring-boot-starter-web` you don't need `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` any more.

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

In general hal browser is pluggged into your apllication with this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId> 
  <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-explorer</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

The version might be different but it has to be available for the appication in runtime
Probably it somehow finds its way into your dependency list

To examine where exactly does this particular dependency come from, run `mvn dependency:tree` and find it in the produced tree. Then you should decide whether you can just remove the dependency "as is" or use exclusions mechanism of the build tool in case of transitivity

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `clean install` on `maven` ?
If problem not solved and if you are using Intellij, then left top, click `File` `invalidate cache restart` (tick on `clear file` also).
Last option is delete `.m2` folder.

https://mkyong.com/maven/where-is-maven-local-repository/